# Getting parent element with delegated event?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to get parent element's id after re-attaching click event to a list item's third a tag (Delete), after list item is added via ajax. The structure looks as follows:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="list_23">
         <a href="javascript:;">Title</a>
         <a href="javascript:;">Edit</a> | <a href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
     </li>
 <ul>
```

The javascript is:

```
$('#list li').on("click", 'a:nth-child(2)', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    console.log( id );
});
```

I am trying to get the list items id (the "list_23"), when third a link is clicked, after element is added via ajax.

Comment: You don't delegate the event.

Comment: Also, looking at your code (`.parent().parent()`) and the expected result of "list_23", you are going up one further node than you need.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code. The problem is that it does not work after the ajax, so the event is not reattached. It works on a list item prior to ajax. Like I am unable to trek parent from the a link after the ajax?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't the proper way to write delegated events with `.on()`. Try the following instead:

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li a:nth-child(3)', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  console.log( id );
});
```

See specifically [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) section of the `.on()` documentation for jQuery.

*Edit: Updated my answer based on the `li` item being the element dynamically added to the DOM.*

*Edit 2: The problem was the `:nth-child(n)` selector is not zero index-based, rather it is one indexed based. Added working JSFiddle.*

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/wyze/vTkYf/

Comment: I am trying this example but can not get it to work - the id is coming back as undefined after ajax. Works fine prior to ajax. jQuery version is 2.0.3.

Comment: Updated answer with correct code along with working JSFiddle.